# R-Shiny Update data frame based off of user input

Tags: r, shiny

If I have a data frame with 4 different columns, 3 of them being categorical and 1 being continuous, I want to get the continuous values of the data frame depending on what categorical values are selected.

That is, I want to stratify/update the data frame whenever the user checks off another radiobutton (or any input really)

For example, if one of the columns was whether they ate food or not, I would like to stratify based off of this, but I don't know how I can continuously update the data frame, I have the option as a radiobutton but

```
mydata = read_excel('thisdata.xlsx')

ui <- .....

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$Food, {
    if (input$Food == "Yes"){
      mydata = mydata[mydata$Food == "Yes", ]
    }
    if (input$Food == "No"){
      mydata = mydata[mydata$Food == "No", ]
    }
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mydata$numCals)
  })
}
```

I was expecting the plot to change as I selected Yes/No on the radiobuttons but the plot remains the same, it's actually as if I were not stratifying at all, it's just taking it all together. How can I obtain something like this?

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* I changed your code for the filter. You don't need the if statement. You could even change to `dplyr::filter()` if you wanted.

The answer using `eventReactive()`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  mydata_new <- eventReactive(input$Food, {
    mydata[mydata$Food == input$Food, ]
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mydata_new()$numCals)
  })

}
```

Comment: I want to also include a summary, so I don't want it to be just in renderPlot

Comment: Try my updates (using `eventReactive()`) and see if they work.

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for responding so late